# Comparing a users password hash efficiently

Tags: c#, php, database, hash

So I have a login system for a user to connect to the database, this includes a salt and hash. However, I'm trying to think of the most efficient way to compare a users login information without making 2 web requests.

So what I have right now is a c# application where the user logins in with their username and password, the username is sent to a PHP file on the server where the row with the matching username is fetched. I then send the salt at this row back, add it to the password and hash it. The resulting hash is then sent to be matched with the hash if successful the user logs in.

The problem I have with this, though it's secure and it works, I have to send 2 web requests and that doesn't seem efficient to me. Does anyone know how to make it more efficient?

I've had the idea of hashing it on the c# side, then sending the username and password together. Then adding the salt to the hash that is sent, then this is what is used to compare with the hash in the database. Of course, the hashing of their password would be done the same way. What do you think?

Comment: Wow! I thought all this salting-hashing should happen on the server.

Comment: Sending the password in plain text is dangerous so I needto hash it on the application side.

Comment: To be honest you're over complicating things or just didn't provide enough information

Comment: Where exactly are you doing what? Is PHP the part that talks to the database? In that case, you should use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). All that should happen in one place.

Comment: What would be less complicated?

Comment: _"Sending the password in plain text is dangerous"_ - That's why you should send things encrypted, using HTTPS.

Comment: When registering, send the username and password to PHP. PHP hashes the password using `password_hash()`. You save the hash in the database. When logging in, you send the username and password to PHP, which fetches the correct user by the username. You then verify the password against the stored hash using `password_verify()` (still in PHP). If it matches, you return success and if it fails, you return fail. And do all requests under HTTPS and it won't be sent in clear text.

Comment: Magnus for president.

Comment: So send information from the C# application using HTTPS? I'm not familiar with HTTPS as I thought it could only be used from a browser, I'll have a look into including it in my C# application, thank you Magnus.

Comment: When you say "sending", you mean a http-request, right? Like to an API? HTTPS is for any http-client, and not specifically for browsers. If you create a request in C# (like calling an API), your application is the client, just like a browser. Basically, you install a SSL certificate on the server (that serves your PHP code) and then you use `https://...` when calling the API. Google for more info about SSL and HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean, I'm not 100% familiar with the jargon of everything just yet.

Comment: No worries. Now you got some pointers. The question is currently too broad to be answered with more specifics.